# finding registry parent folder to add registry

Tags: powershell, registry, powershell-2.0, parent, registrykey

I am stuck at how to actually find the parent folder to add a new registry key using powershell. The reason is because the device shows as a different value per computer. And the registry that I am trying to add will set the default over to the "internal mic"'s parents key. 
Here is the code

```
    $pathToIntMic = Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture | Where-Object { .Name -eq "internal mic"}
    #$intMicParent = (Get-item $pathToIntMic).parent.Fullname
    #write-host $intMicParent
```

The last two line are commented out but serve just to get the parent folder key name just under \Audio\Capture.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the property `PSParentPath`:

```
$key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Capture'
$pathToIntMic = Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\$key" | ? { $_.Name -eq "internal mic" }
Write-Host $pathToIntMic.PSParentPath
```

You can enumerate the properties and methods of an object by piping it into the `Get-Member` cmdlet:

```
$pathToIntMic | Get-Member
```